# I cant create a migration in asp.net core because i keep getting cant construct db context and im using 2 contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I cant create a migration in asp.net core because i keep getting cant construct db context and im using 2 contexts. Ive tried everything to try and fix this but I still cant create migrations because it says it has an error constructing db context and all my code is fine and I cant find out why this wont work. Can someone please help, Thanks.

ApplicationDbContext

```
using GraphQlApiFullStack.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace GraphQlApiFullStack.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

IdentityAppDbContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GraphQlApiFullStack.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace GraphQlApiFullStack.Data
{
    public class IdentityAppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public IdentityAppDbContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

identityServicesExtension.cs

```
using System.Text;
using GraphQlApiFullStack.Data;
using GraphQlApiFullStack.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace GraphQlApiFullStack.Extensions
{
    public static class IdentityServiceExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>();

            builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
            builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityAppDbContext>();
            builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["Token:Key"])),
                    ValidIssuer = config["Token:Issuer"],
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

startup.cs

```
using GraphQL.Server.Ui.Voyager;
using GraphQlApiFullStack.Data;
using GraphQlApiFullStack.Extensions;
using GraphQlApiFullStack.GraphQL;
using GraphQlApiFullStack.Services;
using GraphQlApiFullStack.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace GraphQlApiFullStack
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        // public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "GraphQlApiFullStack", Version = "v1"});
            });

            // We use a pooled Db Context Factory here to avoid issues with graphql concurrency

            services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection"));
            });

            // Identity will use just a normal db context since we wont be making multiple concurrent queries to it.

            services.AddDbContext<IdentityAppDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("identityConnection"));
            });

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            
            services.AddGraphQLServer()
                .AddQueryType<Query>()
                .AddMutationType<Mutation>()
                .AddFiltering()
                .AddSorting()
                .AddProjections();
            
            services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();

            //services.AddIdentityServices(_configuration);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "GraphQlApiFullStack v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapGraphQL();
            });

            app.UseGraphQLVoyager(new VoyagerOptions()
            {
                GraphQLEndPoint = "/graphql"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with Add-Migration ''MigrationName" -Context "ContextName" Or dotnet ef migrations add "MigrationName" --context "ContextName"?

Comment: yup ive tried both of those

Comment: Is it all in the same project or do you have two of them? If so then, do you run your `migrations add` command on project `GraphQlApiFullStack.Data` and use flag `--startup-project GraphQlApiFullStack`

Comment: Ill try this out soon